# Assembly- How to input interrupt and save it in register

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, system-calls

I've written some `macro`s to get input from user and I need to save the input in some register. 
`gdb` shows me that stored value is different from input ! here is my code:

```
%macro exit 0
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80
%endmacro


%macro  get_input 0           ; input is a number
push_all_general_purpose_regs
    push_all_general_purpose_regs
    mov eax, 3                ; system call number --> sys_read
    mov ebx, 2                ; file descriptor
    mov ecx, num               
    mov edx, 4
    int 0x80
    sub dword [num], '0'      ; convert character to number : forexample '3'->3
    POP_all_general_purpose_regs
%endmacro


%macro push_all_general_purpose_regs 0
    push eax
    push ebx
    push ecx
    push edx
%endmacro


%macro POP_all_general_purpose_regs 0
    POP edx
    POP ecx
    POP ebx
    POP eax
%endmacro

section .bss
    num resb 4  ;  num is where input will be stored at

section .text
global _start
_start:

    get_input  
    lea ecx, [num] ; now ecx holds the address of input
    mov ebx, [ecx] ; I want to move input to ebx
    finished:
    exit
```

and here is the output of `gdb`:

```
(gdb) break finished
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80480ad
(gdb) run
Starting program: /assembly-project/main_project/test_project    /sta/a.out
67

Breakpoint 1, 0x080480ad in finished ()
(gdb) info registers
eax            0x0      0
ecx            0x80490b4        134516916
edx            0x0      0
ebx            0xa3706  669446
esp            0xffffd390       0xffffd390
ebp            0x0      0x0
esi            0x0      0
edi            0x0      0
eip            0x80480ad        0x80480ad <finished>
eflags         0x206    [ PF IF ]
cs             0x23     35
ss             0x2b     43
ds             0x2b     43
es             0x2b     43
fs             0x0      0
gs             0x0      0
(gdb)
```

as is seen, my input is `67` but value of `ebx` is `669446`

Comment: Your code only allows for single digit numbers. Also that's gonna be 1 byte but you load 4. You can find your `6` in `bl`.

Comment: Just opinion... why do you introduce those macros at all? They will turn your source into total nightmare for debugging/reviewing, which is usually 60-90% of development time in assembly. If your purpose is to save time on typing, then forget it, that's tiny amount of total development time, reading the source and understanding it is where you can save biggest amount of time. Macros are hard to read, especially parametrized or nested, as you either have to remember all instructions in them, or go up/down in the source to re-read them. Often simple `call procedure` is enough to save you typing.

Comment: @Jester you are right, I didn't notice that.

Comment: @Ped7g Actually, the original project is sth bigger than the code written above. macros help me concentrate at one task at a time .

Comment: IMO you will really regret this kind of macros during debugging later, they will make the code bloat fast... especially as "get_input" is typical case where procedure can be used in almost the same way (just adding `call` ahead of `get_input` and you have almost the same code, but in disassembly in debugger there's no bloat, you will see similar `call <get_input_address>` code, not 20 new instructions which are not in source written directly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`669446` = `0xA3706` and that is your three character input, let me show you.

Your original input is read as three bytes `36 37 0A` (three characters `'6', '7', '\n'`).

The 4th byte in `.bss` is zero, as the `.bss` section is zeroed by linux OS during binary loading+initialization.

I.e. the memory at address `num` contains `dword` value equal to `0x000A3736`.

Then you subtract `0x00000030` from that by `sub dword [num], '0'`, so the result is value `0x000A3706` ... and that is `669446` in decimal, exactly what you got.

So everything works correctly, just in the exact way, as you wrote it.

To input multi-digit decimal integers with `sys_read` service, you will have to parse them character by character, in a loop, like:

```
result = 0
for (digit : input_string) {  // from first to last input character
    if (!is_valid_digit(digit)) break; // will catch '\n', or other invalid char
    result *= 10;
    result += digit - '0';
}
// here "result" is binary integer value equal to the decimal encoded in string.
```